# Syncing Site WF (State Machine) to ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-server, asp.net

I have developed a web form in ASP.NET with the code behind in vb.net in Visual Studio 2013. This will be deployed into SharePoint. I have also included a Site State Machine WF in the same solution. I am not able to get the WF to start on submit button click. Can someone please provide me with some advice on how to get this to work? Is including the Site State Machine WF in my solution the correct way to deploy a WF that isn't associated to a list into SharePoint?

I have deployed my ASP.NET web for and code behind into SharePoint via an application page.

Thank you for any help

Comment: That solution only works if your form is associated with a custom list. Mine is not associated with a custom list. Mine is deployed via an application page in SharePoint.

Comment: The answer might be wrong, but you are asking the same thing in that question as you do here

Comment: Yes, I see. Do you know of any solutions for this issue?